# Should I override a property in child class form parent class (UIButton)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to create a custom button, that will help me change all button background color to default red color if I don't set any color for the button.
So I do like this and it working well

**in .h file I have**

```
@interface ITSButton : UIButton
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *backgroundColor;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *onPressBackgroundColor;
@end
```

**in .m fie**

```
-(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    if(!_backgroundColor){
        _backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return _backgroundColor;
}
```

But the problem here `backgroundColor` is already a property of `UIButton` class. Is it good and clear if I override it in `ITSButton`?

And if I don't override `backgroundColor` property, I can not use the function `(UIColor *)backgroundColor`, so I can not set the default background to red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And if I don't override `backgroundColor` property, I can not use the function `(UIColor*)backgroundColor`, so I can not set the default background to red

Yes you can, and I think that realizing this is probably the key to your dilemma. Leave `backgroundColor` alone! It has an important job to do. Instead, implement the *initializer* of your subclass to *set* the background color of this button to red. You should do this for all possible initializers; the two most likely are `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`.

The result is that all buttons of this class, and all buttons of any subclass of this class, will be red *by default*, which is what you want. And to change that, you just set the background color of the button, just as you do now with any button.

Don't forget to read the docs on how to override an initializer in a subclass if you don't already know the rules on how to do it.

Comment: I understand your solution, so the answer for my question is "I should not override the property backgroundColor" right?

Comment: Right. Just make the button _be_ red by default, because of the way it is initialized.